# I have to append last n element of LL to front

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

```
node* append_LinkedList(node* head,int n)
{
    //write your code here
    int count=0;
    node *temp=head;

    while(count<n-1)
    {
        temp=temp->next;
        count++;
    }
    cout<<temp->data;
    return head;
}
```

next step I am not able to think. After getting nth node pointer what to do next.

Comment: Assuming *font* is supposed to be *front*, front of what? The same list? Another list? A hamburger? I think you've given us too little to work with here. Unless you are very clear in your questions you will only get usable answers when fortune favours you.

Comment: This is a homework problem. Please TRY before asking HOW! You can only become a better programmer if you try. That being said, here is some help. Are you adding n to the list, or adding nothing to the nth position? I believe it is the former. Also, appending data usually refers to adding a node to the back of the list. Get the pointer to the tail, and attach your newly created node to this.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely seems like a homework problem.

Think on the following terms:
Consider the following linked list and you want to move the node C to the front.

`A -> B -> C -> D -> E`

Store your current `head` pointer in a variable. Loop through the linked list until you find `C`. Mark the previous node of `C` to be `null`. Store the `head` to be at `C` and loop until you get to the end of list, which in this case is `E` . Now point the `next` of `E` to the originally stored `head`

So your output will be 
`C -> D -> E -> A -> B`

Answer (score 0):

```
Move last n element to front of a given Linked List. I am not getting correct  output
node* append_LinkedList(node* head,int n)
{
    //write your code here
    int size=0;
    node *temp2=head;
    while(temp2->next!=NULL)
    {
        temp2=temp2->next;
        size++;
    }
    int count=0;
    node *temp=head;
    node *head3=temp;
    while(count<size-n-1)
    {
        temp=temp->next;
        count++;
    }
    head=temp->next;
    temp->next=NULL;

    temp2->next=head3;
    return head;
}
```